# iTunes is preventing display from sleeping when locked

Tags: itunes, catalina, sleep-wake

I've been having an intermittent issue with my MacBook Pro 16" screen not sleeping after having locked it, it just sits on the login screen saying Touch ID or Enter Password. You can manually sleep it by hitting the esc key but otherwise it stays on indefinitely rather than the usual few seconds.

Initially I looked at Bartender as some had reported that could be an issue but despite making the suggested changes, it persisted. Bartender currently isn't running and I can reproduce the issue by locking the screen when iTunes is opening, observe it not sleeping; unlock it, quit iTunes, lock the machine, and it will sleep after 5 seconds.

There is no obvious background activity in iTunes e.g. iCloud sync or iPhone sync.

macOS 10.15.5
MacBook Pro 16" 2019

If anyone has any suggestions that would be grand.
Thanks

**edit**: The issue persists after reboot, even when booting with no other apps running other than iTunes. 
This machine is only a couple of weeks old so reinstalling Catalina seems a step too far at the minute.
[image: Music preventing sleep]

Comment: Launch Activity Monitor [Apps/Utilities] then from the View menu, select 'All Processes'. Right click on any column header & check 'Preventing Sleep' then click this new header until anything doing that sorts to the top. Let us know what says 'Yes'.

Comment: Yep there's a few things in that category.
`hidd`
`FirefoxCP Web Content`
`AirPlayXPCHelper`
`Music`

Comment: hidd will get out of your way when necessary, so you don't need to worry about that. The other two are what's preventing sleep. For Firefox you'll need to figure out which tab is responsible. Radio stations do that, I don't think YouTube does, but I'm not certain. AirPlay I have no experience with, so idk what will keep that running.

Comment: Problem is persisting fairly regularly, Music is the only consistent process preventing sleep.

Comment: I've never actually seen Catalina, so I don't know how the Music app works at all. If it's quotable, you'll have to quit it, I guess.